# Drag and drop item renderer(panel) within list

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I have a spark List,its item renderer is a panel,and in the panel there are some components such as Textinput,now I want to drag and drop a panel within the List,how can I do that,could you pls show me the code,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The list in flex has a default drag and drop functionality. So basically all you need to do is to set 3 properties to true to your list:
`dragMoveEnabled`, `dragEnabled` and `dropEnabled`. So your list if you add it from mxml will look like this:

```
<s:List dataProvider="{yourDataProvider}" dragMoveEnabled="true" dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" />
```

For more details about these 3 properties you can check the spark list documentation:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#dragMoveEnabled

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.Now I catch an error while draging the itemRenderer(my flex sdk is 4.5.1).
My list itemRenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            width="100%" height="100%">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;


        override public function set data(value:Object ) : void{
            super.data = value;
        }

        protected function closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
            //ToDo
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
    <s:TitleWindow x="0" y="0" title="{data.label}"
               width="100%" height="100%" creationPolicy="all"
               skinClass="skin.titleWindowSkin" 
               close="closeHandler(event)">
    <s:Label text="{data.value}"/>

    <s:TextInput x="123" y="58" text="@{data.value}" 
                 focusIn="parentDocument.owner.dragEnabled=false" 
                 focusOut="parentDocument.owner.dragEnabled=true"/>

</s:TitleWindow>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

While draging,catch an error like:
Error: Skin for DragProxy261.ListItemDragProxy260.DspDesktopItemRenderer262._DspDesktopItemRenderer_TitleWindow1.titleWindowSkin264.Group265.contents._titleWindowSkin_Group5.contentGroup._DspDesktopItemRenderer_TextInput1 cannot be found.
    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableComponent/attachSkin()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableComponent.as:698]